# Sql - Merge select - Criar row caso registro inexistente

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou querendo unir dois `SELECT`, mas estou sem sucesso.

#### Possui as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_producao
(
  cd_producao SERIAL,
  cd_setor integer,
  nr_quantidade numeric(12,2),
  ds_producao character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_mapa_producao
(
  cd_mapa_producao SERIAL,
  cd_lote_producao_ordem_ticket integer,
  cd_setor integer,
  dt_inicio timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE TABLE tb_setor
(
  cd_setor SERIAL,
  ds_setor character varying(200) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tb_lote_producao_ordem_ticket
(
  cd_lote_producao_ordem_ticket SERIAL,
  cd_lote_producao_ordem integer,
  nr_quantidade numeric(12,0) DEFAULT 0
);
```

#### E o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT
    S.cd_setor as "cd_setor", 
    SUM(COALESCE(LPOT.nr_quantidade,0)) as "nr_total_ticket",
    SUM(CASE MP.fl_desativado WHEN TRUE THEN LPOT.nr_quantidade ELSE 0 END) as "nr_total_concluido",
    (   
        SELECT  COALESCE((SUM(COALESCE(P.nr_quantidade,0)) / CASE WHEN count(P.cd_producao) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE count(P.cd_producao) END)::numeric(12,2),0) as "P.ds_media_producao"
        FROM    tb_producao P 
        WHERE   P.cd_setor = S.cd_setor
    ) as "nr_media_producao"
    ,date_trunc('day', CASE WHEN MP.dt_inicio IS NULL THEN now() ELSE MP.dt_inicio END) as "dt_producao"
FROM
    tb_setor S
    LEFT JOIN tb_mapa_producao MP ON S.cd_setor = MP.cd_setor
    LEFT JOIN tb_lote_producao_ordem_ticket LPOT ON LPOT.cd_lote_producao_ordem_ticket = MP.cd_lote_producao_ordem_ticket
WHERE
    (
        (date_trunc('day', MP.dt_inicio) = date_trunc('day', now()))
        OR MP.cd_mapa_producao IS NULL
    )
GROUP BY    1,5
UNION
    SELECT
        S.cd_setor as "cd_setor", 
        null,
        null,
        (   
            SELECT  COALESCE((SUM(COALESCE(P.nr_quantidade,0)) / CASE WHEN count(P.cd_producao) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE count(P.cd_producao) END)::numeric(12,2),0) as "P.ds_media_producao"
            FROM    tb_producao P 
            WHERE   P.cd_setor = S.cd_setor
        ) as "nr_media_producao",
        now()
    FROM
        tb_setor S
ORDER BY 
    1,5
```

#### Resultado :

```
1   |   120 |   70  |   1000.00 |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
1   |       |       |   1000.00 |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
2   |   120 |   70  |   870.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
2   |       |       |   870.00  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
3   |   0   |   0   |   733.33  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
3   |       |       |   733.33  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
4   |   0   |   0   |   850.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
4   |       |       |   850.00  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
5   |   120 |   70  |   950.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
5   |       |       |   950.00  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
6   |   120 |   110 |   900.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
6   |       |       |   900.00  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
7   |       |       |   966.67  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
8   |   0   |   0   |   866.67  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
8   |       |       |   866.67  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
9   |       |       |   690.00  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
10  |   0   |   0   |   600.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
10  |       |       |   600.00  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
```

#### Resultado esperado

```
1   |   120 |   70  |   1000.00 |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
2   |   120 |   70  |   870.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
3   |   0   |   0   |   733.33  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
4   |   0   |   0   |   850.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
5   |   120 |   70  |   950.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
6   |   120 |   110 |   900.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
7   |   0   |   0   |   966.67  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
8   |   0   |   0   |   866.67  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
9   |   0   |   0   |   690.00  |   "2015-10-14 11:02:52.183443-03"
10  |   0   |   0   |   600.00  |   "2015-10-14 00:00:00-03"
```

#### Objetivo

Quero calcular a produtividade do dia atual, contudo caso não haja produção no dia, deve apenas calcular a `nr_media_producao` do setor e manter os demais campos com `0` ou `now()`.

#### Situação

Com o `UNION` eu consegui que sempre calcule a `nr_media_producao`, mas quando ha produção no dia me gera registros duplicados, ou seja gostaria de um `merge` que de preferencia para a `query` que possui produção no dia.

#### OBS

Eu gostaria de usar o `sqlfiddle` para demostrar os dados, mas ele gera erro quando tento compilar. devido a muitas linhas.

Comment: Guilherme, poderia colocar qual resultado espera? Você tem os Inserts das tabelas?

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates editei colocando resultado esperado, quanto aos insert eu tenho, mas são muitos a sqlfiddle não suportou, vou ver onde posso por.

Comment: pus no [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/xK6hS7/1), mas apenas para pode le mostrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explicação

Você pode utilizar o seu select como base de uma tabela derivada, possibilitando a utilização de um filtro para manter os demais campos com `0` ou `now()`.

Utilizamos a função `ROW_NUMBER()` para contabilizar quantas linhas estão repetidas (particionadas pelo `ID`, já que ele se repete), e ordenei para que as colunas que não forem `NULL` tenham "prioridade" na ordenação, neste caso, utilizamos uma tabela derivada como base para outra tabela derivada.

Ao final, só foi necessário selecionar as colunas separadamente para que a contagem das linhas não fosse exibida.

## Query

```
 SELECT 
      CD_SETOR, 
      NR_TOTAL_TICKET, 
      NR_MEDIA_PRODUCAO,
      NR_TOTAL_CONCLUIDO
 FROM (
         SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cd_setor ORDER BY NR_TOTAL_TICKET ASC) RN FROM (   
                SELECT
                    S.cd_setor as "cd_setor", 
                    SUM(COALESCE(LPOT.nr_quantidade,0)) as "nr_total_ticket",
                    SUM(CASE MP.fl_desativado WHEN TRUE THEN LPOT.nr_quantidade ELSE 0 END) as "nr_total_concluido",
                    (   
                        SELECT  COALESCE((SUM(COALESCE(P.nr_quantidade,0)) / CASE WHEN count(P.cd_producao) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE count(P.cd_producao) END)::numeric(12,2),0) as "P.ds_media_producao"
                        FROM    tb_producao P 
                        WHERE   P.cd_setor = S.cd_setor
                    ) as "nr_media_producao"
                    ,date_trunc('day', CASE WHEN MP.dt_inicio IS NULL THEN now() ELSE MP.dt_inicio END) as "dt_producao"
                FROM
                    tb_setor S
                    LEFT JOIN tb_mapa_producao MP ON S.cd_setor = MP.cd_setor
                    LEFT JOIN tb_lote_producao_ordem_ticket LPOT ON LPOT.cd_lote_producao_ordem_ticket = MP.cd_lote_producao_ordem_ticket
                WHERE
                    (
                        (date_trunc('day', MP.dt_inicio) = date_trunc('day', now()))
                        OR MP.cd_mapa_producao IS NULL
                    )
                GROUP BY    1,5
                UNION
                    SELECT
                        S.cd_setor as "cd_setor", 
                        null,
                        null,
                        (   
                            SELECT  COALESCE((SUM(COALESCE(P.nr_quantidade,0)) / CASE WHEN count(P.cd_producao) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE count(P.cd_producao) END)::numeric(12,2),0) as "P.ds_media_producao"
                            FROM    tb_producao P 
                            WHERE   P.cd_setor = S.cd_setor
                        ) as "nr_media_producao",
                        now()
                    FROM
                        tb_setor S
                ORDER BY 
                    1,5 ) A ) B WHERE B.RN = 1
```

Comment: não resolveu, pois assim ele exclui os dados do setor 7 e 9 no dia 14. pois os mesmo vai estar null quanto a ticket. mas devem estar presentes no resultado como comentei.

Comment: Guilherme, pode testar novamente?

Comment: funcionou apenas tive que alterar `DESC` para `ASC` em `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cd_setor ORDER BY NR_TOTAL_TICKET)`. Se possível poderia comentar explicando? compreendi o resultado, mas não os meios.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, veja se está melhor.